# How to select specific text from a string generated by a PHP script?

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping, http-live-streaming, m3u8

I've been trying to scrape a HLS file from Twitch using several PHP scripts. The first one runs a cURL command to get the HLS URL through a Python script that returns said URL and converts the generated string to plain text, and the second (which is the one that isn't working) is supposed the extract the M3U8 file and make it able to be played.

**First script (*extract.php*)**

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
$url = "https://pwn.sh/tools/streamapi.py?url=twitch.tv/cgtn_live_russian&quality=1080p60";

$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

//for debug only!
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$resp = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
var_dump($resp);
$undesirable = array("}");
$cleanurl = str_replace($undesirable,"");
echo substr($cleanurl, 39, 898);

?>
```

This script (let's call it *extract.php*) works, and it returns (in plain text) the same information the Python script would return, which is this:

```
string(904) "{"success": true, "urls": {"1080p60": "https://video-weaver.fra05.hls.ttvnw.net/v1/playlist/[token].m3u8"}}"
```

**Second script (*play.php*)**

```
<?php
$opts = array(
'http'=>array(
'method'=>"GET",
'header'=>"Referer:https://myserver.com/" .
  "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:51.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/51.0"
));

$html = file_get_contents("extract.php");

preg_match_all(
    '/(http.*?\.m3u8[^&">]+)/',

    $html,
    $posts, // will contain the article data
    PREG_SET_ORDER // formats data into an array of posts
);

foreach ($posts as $post) {
    $link = $post[0];

header("Location: $link");
}
?>
```

This second script (let's call it *play.php*) should theoretically return the M3U8 file (without *string(904) "{"success": true, "urls": {"1080p60":*) and make it able to be played in a media player, such as VLC, but it doesn't return anything.

Can someone tell me what's wrong? Did I make a syntax or regex error when making these PHP files or is the second file not working because of the other elements of the string?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you want to `include("extract.php")` instead of `file_get_contents("extract.php")`. The `include()` function runs the file, whereas `file_get_contents()` just returns the contents of the file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've made a new script and replaced `file_get_contents` for `include`, but now it returns the same thing as `extract.php` instead of the m3u8 file only. I think the second script doesn't recognize the url because it's in the middle of a string.

Comment: You should post your `extract.php`, too hard to tell what's going on without that.

Comment: `extract.php` is the first script I posted in my question, which is the one that grabs the information generated by this `pwn.sh` Python script and prints it in plain text. Maybe I should somehow modify it to remove everything that's not part of the URL, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can rely on the regex to get the URL out instead of trying to clean the string manually. The other way would be to use `json_decode()`.

Anyways the idea is to define a variable in `extract.php`, in this case it is `$resp`. Doing it via `echo` as you are now will not make it available in the parent script.

You can then reference that variable in `play.php` once `extract.php` has been included.

```
<?php
//extract.php
$resp = '';
$url = "https://pwn.sh/tools/streamapi.py?url=twitch.tv/cgtn_live_russian&quality=1080p60";

$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

//for debug only!
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$resp = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);


//play.php
include('./extract.php');

//$resp is set in extraact.php
preg_match_all(
    '/(http.*?\.m3u8)/',
    $resp,
    $posts, // will contain the article data
    PREG_SET_ORDER // formats data into an array of posts
);

foreach ($posts as $post) {
    $link = $post[0];
}

header("Location: $link");
die();
```

Comment: Thank you so much man! The script worked! It now grabs the M3U8 file instead of the string, thank you